# find shape and color circle

Tags: opencv

I have detected just all the red contours  and am struggling to find a way to run a shape detection algorithm on these contours to get just red circules  but don't know how to extract just red circle and eliminate the undesirable rest of contours ? Source Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include"math.h"
#include"conio.h"
#include"cv.h"
#include"highgui.h"
#include"stdio.h"
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    int h,w,seuill,channels;
    int seuilr, channelsr;
    int temp=0;
    uchar *data,*datar;
    i=j=k=0;
    IplImage *frame=cvLoadImage("Mon_image.jpg",1);
    IplImage *result=cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    IplImage *gray=cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    cvCvtColor(frame, result, CV_BGR2GRAY );

    //IplImage* gray;
    cvNamedWindow("original",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("Result",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    h = frame->height;
    w = frame->width;
    seuill =frame->widthStep;
    channels = frame->nChannels;
    data = (uchar *)frame->imageData;


    seuilr=result->widthStep;
    channelsr=result->nChannels;
    datar = (uchar *)result->imageData;

   for(i=0;i < (h);i++) 
    for(j=0;j <(w);j++)
{     
if(((data[i*seuill+j*channels+2]) >(19+data[i*seuill+j*channels]))&& ((data[i*seuill+j*channels+2]) > (19+data[i*seuill+j*channels+1])))

            datar[i*seuilr+j*channelsr]=255;

else
    datar[i*seuilr+j*channelsr]=0;
}       

         cvCanny(result,result, 50, 100, 3);
          CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
         CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(result, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 40.0, 100, 100,0,0);

    cvShowImage("original",frame);
    cvShowImage("Result",result);
    cvSaveImage("result.jpg",result);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvDestroyWindow("original");
    cvDestroyWindow("Result");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sharing input and output images of the current application will not only improve the quality of your question but also the chances to get an answer. And tag your question better. All the **C** guys out there are probably missing this question because it ain't tagged as so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple object detection using OpenCV and machine learning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416117/simple-object-detection-using-opencv-and-machine-learning)

Comment: Most probably, duplicate of: [Detecting a circle of a specific color (or gray level) with openCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198237/detecting-a-circle-of-a-specific-color-or-gray-level-with-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

I will rather use RANSAC algorithm to detect circle in your set of contours but, Hough transform will also do the work.
See [here](http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/MIP/Teaching/ip/ex06/) for an explication of the both process. Solution in matlab in given.